# InvalidOperationException on bulk insert

Tags: c#

I have a .Net application where the user can upload a formatted csv file. The program parses the values, and then uploads them to our database.

Problem was that the original programmer created a loop and a sql insert statement for each row of data. On some of the larger csv files, this can end up taking hours.

I've decided to rememdy the problem by putting the data into a datatable and doing a bulk update. Problem I'm getting is `InvalidOperationException` on my `.WriteToServer` line

Here is my code

```
  Guid jobId = Guid.NewGuid();
            int goodRows = 0, badRows = 0;

            DataTable bulkSimulatorData = new DataTable();
            bulkSimulatorData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("jobId", typeof(string)));
            bulkSimulatorData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
            bulkSimulatorData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));
            bulkSimulatorData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(string)));

            if (CDR.PostedFile != null && CDR.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {


                StreamReader csvReader = new StreamReader(CDR.PostedFile.InputStream);
                {
                    string inputLine = "";
                    SimulatorCDR cdr = null;


                    while ((inputLine = csvReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            string[] values = inputLine.Split(new Char[] { ',' });
                            if (values.Length == 4)
                            {
                                bulkSimulatorData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column4", typeof(string)));
                                cdr = new SimulatorCDR(jobId, values[0].ToString(), values[1].ToString(), Convert.ToDecimal(values[2]), Convert.ToDecimal(values[3]));
                                if (cdr.Save())
                                {
                                    bulkSimulatorData.Rows.Add(jobId, values[0].ToString(), values[1].ToString(), Convert.ToDecimal(values[2]), Convert.ToDecimal(values[3]));
                                    goodRows++;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    badRows++;
                                }


                            }
                            else
                            {
                                cdr = new SimulatorCDR(jobId, values[0].ToString(), values[1].ToString(), Convert.ToDecimal(values[2]));
                                if (cdr.Save())
                                {
                                    bulkSimulatorData.Rows.Add(jobId, values[0].ToString(), values[1].ToString(), Convert.ToDecimal(values[2]));
                                    goodRows++;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    badRows++;
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        catch(Exception ex)
                        {

                        }




                    }

                    csvReader.Close();
                }
            }

            if (goodRows > 0)
            {
                string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DTH"].ConnectionString;
                string trafficType = Conversational.Checked ? "CONVO" : "DIALER";
                using(SqlBulkCopy oSqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(constring))
                {
                    oSqlBulkCopy.BatchSize = goodRows;
                    oSqlBulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 100000;
                    oSqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("JobID", "JobID");
                    oSqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Column1", "SourceNumber");
                    oSqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Column2", "DestNumber");
                    oSqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Column3", "Duration");
                    oSqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "[RATESIM].[dbo].[CDR]";
                    oSqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(bulkSimulatorData);

                }
                string sql = "exec RATESIM.dbo.spQueueRatingSimulatorJob '" + jobId + "', '" + Utils.sanitize(Name.Text) + "', '" + Email.Text + "', '" + Utils.sanitize(Phone.Text) + "', '" + trafficType + "'";
                if (Utils.ExecuteSQL("DTH", sql, 100))
                {
                    Message.Text = "Parsed " + goodRows + " CDRs in " + (goodRows + badRows) + " lines. A report will be sent to your email address after processing is complete.";
                    Message.CssClass = "did_success";
                }

            }
```

Comment: Does the exception contain any useful information?

Comment: Unfortunately not 
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: put a try-catch around the bulk copy code and update your question with the exception.

Comment: So... this is strange. I did what you said, and as a result my program worked. The data was successfully put into my database.

Comment: all you did was put the try-catch around it? did you step through it?

Comment: I did. I have no idea why this is suddenly working.

Comment: can you take it off and step through again? typically when something like this happens, i would debug it again to make sure there wasn't some weird loose end..